# Initialize array of custom objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have data coming in from the db I need to store in a js array of objects. How do I initialize this js array of objects , so that I can keep adding the data when I get it from the db .

The object structure will be of this format

```
var OsNames = [{deviceName:"TV",
releases: [
{release: "rel1", hws : [{hw:"h1"},{hw:"h2"},{hw:"h3"}]},
{release: "rel2", hws: [{hw:"h1"},{hw:"h2"},{hw:"h3"}]}
]},
{deviceName:"Phone",
  releases: [
  {release: "rel1", hws: [{hw:"h1"},{hw:"h2"},{hw:"h3"}]},
  {release: "rel2", hws: [{hw:"h1"},{hw:"h2"},{hw:"h3"}]}]
}];
```

Comment: var OsNames = []. OsNames = OsNames.concat(dbResult)

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you from adding items to the array, e.g. via [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Are you looking for an [ODM](http://mongoosejs.com/)?

Comment: Its not clear to me . Array can be empty . When you get data just push it ...

Answer (score 2):

```
var OsNames = [];
```

You can add data to Array by pushing elements in it when you get it from the db

e.g.

```
OsNames.push({release: "rel1", hws : [{hw:"h1"},{hw:"h2"},{hw:"h3"});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that is what you are looking for.

```
var osNames = [];
// Get Data from Database
var myData = ajax.get(...);
for (var i=0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    osNames.push(myData[i]);
}
```